# Angular GET petition with Authorization header

Tags: java, angularjs, api, rest

I have an endpoint [http://localhost:8080/cagb-api/api/merchants/asobancaria/accounts] that receives an Authorization Header:

Authorization :  Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ

But it doesn't need additional parameters, so I created an Angular Service:

```
"use strict";

app.factory('accountsService', accountsService);

function accountsService($localStorage, $resource, SECURE_CONSTANTS){

    var getAsobancariaAccountsRestService = $resource('http://localhost:8080/cagb-api/api/merchants/asobancaria/accounts', {}, 
    {
        getAsobancaria: {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: { 
                'Content-Type': 'application/json' ,
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + $localStorage.token
            },
            transformRequest: function(data, headersGetter) {
                headersGetter = {
                    'Accept': 'application/json'                    
                };
                data = JSON.stringify(data);
                return data;
            }
        }
    });

    return {

        /** Loads the all Asobancaria Accounts for an Account */
        getAsobancariaAccounts : function(successCallback, errorCallback) {
            getAsobancariaAccountsRestService.getAsobancaria({},
                function(data){
                successCallback(data);
            }, function(error){
                errorCallback(error.data);
            });
        },

    };

}
```

And in the controller I call it here:

```
"use strict";

app.controller('technicalConfigurationController', technicalConfigurationController);

function technicalConfigurationController($scope, $translate, accountsService) {

    var successCallback = function (result) {
       console.log(result);
    };

    var errorCallback = function (result) {
        if (result.errorMessage !== undefined) {
            $scope.message = $translate.instant(result.errorMessage);
        } else {
            $scope.message = $translate.instant('DEFAULT_APP_ERROR');
        }
    };

    $scope.getAsobancariaAccounts = function(){
        accountsService.getAsobancariaAccounts(successCallback, errorCallback);
    };

}
```

But when I called the service with a button `<input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="update" ng-click="updateAsobancariaAccounts()">` I get this error: `Error: $resource:badcfg
Response does not match configured parameter`

I have other [POST] services made in the same way but receiving parameters from the resquest:

```
var createAsobancariaAccountRestService = $resource(SECURE_CONSTANTS.SECURE_API_HOST + SECURE_CONSTANTS.SECURE_API_ENDPOINTS.MERCHANTS + SECURE_CONSTANTS.SECURE_API_RESOURCES.ASOBANCARIA_ACCOUNTS, {
        accountName: '@accountName',
        accountNumber: '@accountNumber',
        accountType: '@accountType',
        bankId: '@bankId',
        paymentMethodMain: '@paymentMethodMain',
        lastUpdateSession: '@lastUpdateSession',
        lastUpdateUser: '@lastUpdateUser'
    }, {
        create: {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + $localStorage.token
            },
            transformRequest: function(data, headersGetter) {
                headersGetter = {
                    'Accept': 'application/json'    
                };
                data = JSON.stringify(data);
                return data;
            }
        }
    });

return {
    createAsobancariaAccount: function(asobancariaAccount, successCallback, errorCallback) {
        createAsobancariaAccountRestService.create({
            accountName: asobancariaAccount.accountName,
            accountNumber: asobancariaAccount.accountNumber,
            accountType: asobancariaAccount.accountType,
            bankId: asobancariaAccount.bankId,
            paymentMethodMain: asobancariaAccount.paymentMethodMain,
            lastUpdateSession: asobancariaAccount.lastUpdateSession,
            lastUpdateUser: asobancariaAccount.lastUpdateUser
        }, function(data){
            successCallback(data);
        }, function(error){
            errorCallback(error.data);
        });
    }
};
```